# 3D audio in android

Tags: android, audio, 3d

I am trying to create an application to generate 3D audio in android. I am using the soundpool class and am able to create panning effect (Left Right audio generated at an angle of 90 degrees from the listener). I am wondering if I could apply some algorithm to create 3D positional audio say coming from 45 degrees.
Thanks

Comment: Any success on this? kindly update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your codding experience is but maybe the android class [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) is what you are looking for. On the documentation you can probably find what you are looking for. I saw somewhere that you have to  create an instance, feed it with audio and set the panning with setStereoVolume. Then you just need to convert the 3D audio sources into left and right stereo volume and you have 3D sound in Android.

Hope that helps.